# Database closing in phonegap

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova, cordova-plugins

In my phonegap application i got this error.

```
[INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "forcibly closing database"
```

what i have in my project try to access the database in plugin(background service plugin) this cause the problem.

I used this [Background service plugin](http://red-folder.blogspot.in/2012/09/phonegap-android-background-service.html) worked well in nexus devices but not in Samsung devices

How to solve this issue.
Sample code:

```
function selectUser() {

var query = " userid,islogged FROM user where islogged=1";
transactionSelect(query,"login");
}

function transactionSelect(query,str){
db = window.openDatabase(DATABASE_NAME, DATABASE_VERSION, DATABASE_NAME, 10000000);

newStr = str;

db.transaction(
         function(tx){
             tx.executeSql("SELECT "+query,[],returnExistingUser,noDBError);
 });
}

// query returns success


function returnExistingUser(results){
//alert(JSON.stringify(results));

if (results.rows.length == 0) {
    window.location.hash = "#loginpage";

} else {
    userName = results.rows.item(0).userid;
    // background service called here
    getServiceStatus();
    storeObject.userId = "userId";
    if(device.model == "SM-T331" || device.model == "SM-T210" || device.model == "SM-T111" || device.model == "SM-T110"){
        setTimeout(function(){
            window.location.hash = "#viewpage";
        },4000);
    }else{
        window.location.hash = "#viewpage";
    }
}
$.mobile.autoInitialize();
}
```

in service(plugin)

```
public void getLoggedUser() {

     String sqlQuery = "SELECT userid FROM user WHERE islogged=1";
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sqlQuery, null);

        if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0){
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            do {
                username = cursor.getString(0);
            }while(cursor.moveToNext());
            Log.e("uname", username);
            if(username != null){
                //here another query will e exec
                getOrders(username);
            }
        }else{
            //Log.e("no data", "no data");
            db.close();
        }
}
```

Comment: show some code  what you are trying to do ?

Comment: at which line you are getting this error? and what is the behavior of your app after getting this error ?

Comment: @SweetWisherシ there is no specific line the logcat is `01-02 13:13:25.944: I/chromium(8452): [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "forcibly closing database", source: file:///android_asset/www/html/index.html#viewpage (0)`

Comment: Is it affecting your app ?

Comment: @SweetWisherシ yes the app not retrieve any records from DB...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68074/discussion-between-sweetwisher--and-anu).